# Transitions scale() vs. width/height in different browsers

Tags: css, webkit, gpu, css-transitions, mozilla

I stumbled upon big problem, where firefox couldn't render `scale()` in normal quality, so I decided to go and just set `width/height/top/left` and transition that. But now chrome is rendering in low quality,almost 5-8 FPS and safari just lags in between and shows end result.

I read that if you want to trigger GPU rendering for chrome you just need to add `translate3d()` or 'translateZ()' to your `-webkit-transform` values, but it won't help anymore.

Another thing is, I can't really rely on computers GPU performance, because I need to smooth animations as smooth as I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For triggering GPU rendering have you added the following:

`.selector {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
}`

Even if translate3d is at 0,0,0 it will trigger Hardware Acceleration, but without seeing your code i'm not sure what else to recommend?

Comment: So I found the problem, problem was I had to much PNG resizing. Because Chrome and Safari is Quality > Performance , it was very expensive to calculate all the png's so that's why width/height was so awfull. But if I use scale Chrome and Safari did their own less expensive calculations on those images.

Comment: I will accept your answer even thou it's not the actual answer :D

Comment: skmasq, i know this might be a little late, but what about scaling the PNG's parent instead of the PNG itself?

Comment: Well it really doesn't matter, because FF has very bad performance with extensive 2d and 3d animations, I actually didn't do research why is that, but I have tried a lot of things and using transforms in FF is terrible. That's why I switched to GreenSock Tween plug-in which animates over time not frames. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: skmasq.. FF doesn't have bad performance when doing 2d or 3d transforms.. you just have to apply the transforms correctly! I use GSAP Tween plugin and its awesome, but its just a tool, animating the right way for cross browser. So to say Firefox transforms are terrible, is not correct, They perform quite well when applied right, even without GSAP!

Comment: Shame you accepted as an answer - might put others off from putting a real answer here for future refrence...

Comment: Not shame.. that is how StackOverflow works.. if you have another answer, then post your answer.. an accepted answer doesn't or shouldn't stop others from sharing their solutions. Plus the above question didn't provide an example so it would be hard to know what worked.. since it's a general question with no example for context. There are other ways to solve scale() issues in Firefox, using perspective and preserve-3d.